# How to pass pointer to array of structures?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

```
struct A
{
    struct one
    {
    int c;
    } details[MAX];
};

struct B
{
    struct two
    {
    int a;
    A::one b
    } details[MAX];
};
```

There is a validate function used  like below to validate details array of struct in struct A:

```
bool ValidateOne(struct one * ptr)
{
    struct one * tmp[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) 
        tmp[i] = ptr+i;
    Validate(tmp[0]);
}
```

then there is validations needs to be done on details array of struct B:
I expect to do:

```
bool ValidateTwo(struct two * ptr)
{
    struct one * tmp[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) 
        tmp[i] = &((ptr+i)->b);
    Validate(tmp[0]);
   //validate other stuff
};

Validate(struct one * ptrs[])
{
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) 
        count += ptrs[i]->a;
}
```

Would above code work?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. `B::two` purports to have a member of type `struct one` - but there's no such class; there's instead a class named `A::one`. `ValidateOne` function attempts to access a member named `one::a` - but `struct one` doesn't have such a member.

Comment: `ValidateOne` expects an array of `one` - a block of memory where several instances of `one` are laid out sequentially, side by side. `tmp` however is an array of pointers to `one` - a block of memory where pointers are laid out side by side, but the actual objects they point to are not. `struct two` just doesn't have a block of memory in the form that `ValidateOne` expects: no amount of pointer trickery will produce one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can I define a function validate(struct one * ptr[]) and then call in ValidateOne and ValidateTwo by creating an array of pointers and passing to validate function. In validate function, I can access objects as ptr[0], ptr[1]..etc.. would that work?

Comment: Yes it would work. But personally, I'd just have a function that validates a single instance of `struct one`, then have `ValidateOne` and `ValidateTwo` call it in a loop. This way, you avoid unnecessary memory allocation and copying.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I need to process them together to check for duplicates in that array of structures etc.. and also without using too many loop iterations

Comment: You can define an iterator type which knows how to get to the next item in the array. "A::iterator" would operate on a simple array of "one". "B::iterator"  would operate on an array of B::two. In this way you don't need to create a seperate array of pointers in either case, just two different implementations of the iterator. If done with templates, then "ValidateOne()" must also be a template. If done with virtual functions, then no templates are needed.

Comment: Assuming your real code uses legacy arrays, raw pointers, `struct`, and public everything just like your example, just make `ValidateOne` accept an array of `two`.

Comment: @joeking Thanks, I implemented your suggestion, exactly what I needed in my situation. I used templates and an iterator. Feel free to move your comment as an answer and I would accept it.

Comment: @Medicine Great. You could post you solution as well - others may not understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an iterator type which knows how to get to the next item in the array. "A::iterator" would operate on a simple array of "one". "B::iterator" would operate on an array of B::two.

In this way you don't need to create a seperate array of pointers in either case, just two different implementations of the iterator.

If done with templates, then "ValidateOne()" must also be a template. If done with virtual functions, then no templates are needed.